# Waterfalls you can walk behind near Maryland, USA

Tags: where-on-earth, nature-and-wildlife, geography, maryland, waterfalls

My girlfriend has always wanted to stand behind a waterfall. I'm hoping to propose to her at one. Anybody know of any near Maryland, USA?

Comment: How far are you willing to go? New York? California? Europe? Canada?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Let's just read that as "Nearest waterfalls you can walk behind to Maryland, USA". But Europe might have to wait until the honeymoon (-;

Comment: It was more that those are the places I'd found so far with them, so was wondering if NY was close enough, then dumped in the other 3 as well :)

Comment: Niagara Falls is the canonical waterfall in North America, and you can walk behind it (though it's not terribly romantic in a concrete tunnel with hundreds of other people wearing a disposable poncho raincoat.)

Comment: @MarkMayo Ideally we're talking a day trip from Frederick, MD.

Comment: So just wondering you can actually walk behind the waterfall at Jefferson City national forest? I am wanting to propose there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you and your girlfriend are willing to go for a hot summer hike and cold swim, there is Upper Little Stoney Falls in the [Jefferson National Forest](http://www.fs.usda.gov/main/gwj/home) - [Hanging Rock Day Use Area](http://www.fs.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsinternet/!ut/p/c4/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3gDfxMDT8MwRydLA1cj72BTJw8jAwjQL8h2VAQAzHJMsQ!!/?ss=110808&ttype=recarea&recid=73735&actid=50&navtype=BROWSEBYSUBJECT&position=BROWSEBYSUBJECT&navid=110160000000000&pnavid=110000000000000&cid=null&pname=George%20Washington%20&%20Jefferson%20National%20Forest%20-%20Hanging%20Rock%20Day%20Use%20Area), near Dungannon, Virginia.

Waterfall photos: http://www.waterfall-picture-guide.com/upper-little-stoney-falls.html

Comment: That looks potentially romantic indeed! At least for outdoors types. I wouldn't want to arrive at the spot with a tired and annoyed girlfriend though!

Comment: This looks really good. Only downside is the 4 1/2 hour drive from where I live (Frederick, MD). I'll consider it though. Any other suggestions?